# Why is this background render/script for the command line not working?

Tags: python, rendering, command-line

I'm trying to run Blender as a background process via batch process (or directly from the command line), neither seem to work.  Has anyone done this before?  I'm using the following pages for guidance:

- https://www.blender.org/manual/advanced/command_line/arguments.html
- https://www.blender.org/manual/render/workflows/command_line.html

When rendering, it should use the info in the .blend file (.PNG vs AVI, frame rate, etc.) by default.  For both of these, there is a file called ANIMATION.blend already created.

**Here is the FIRST script, to render in the background:**

```
cd\program files\blender foundation\blender
blender -b C:\pathtofile\ANIMATION.blend -o C:\pathtofile\renders\ -x
```

**It gives me:**

```
found bundled python: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\python
read blend: C:\pathtofile\ANIMATION.blend 

Blender quit
```

But does not actually render anything, either in /tmp, or the output file above, or the one in the .blend file already.

If I just render the animation via the in Blender GUI, it works fine.

Any ideas? Is it broken or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't given the command to render the animation, which is `-a`. The command line isn't just for rendering, so unless you explicitly tell blender you want to render, it won't.

Your first command should look like this:

```
blender -b C:\pathtofile\ANIMATION.blend -o C:\pathtofile\renders\ -x -a
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked!  Now I have a new problem, it says there is no camera present, I'll figure that one out myself.

Comment: Creating the animation .blend file from the command line still doesn't work, though. :)

Comment: 'No camera present' means there isn't a camera in the file that it can render from. You have to add a camera object. As for the animation file, it probably means there is an error in your Python script.

Comment: Thanks again!  Solved it with the follow line, highlighted:

Comment: cam = bpy.data.cameras.new("Camera")
 cam_obj = bpy.data.objects.new("Camera", cam)
 bpy.context.scene.objects.link(cam_obj)
 bpy.context.scene.camera = cam_obj        <--added this line